# I can't use subprocess with python-socketio

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, subprocess

I ensure `towork()` function creates a thread, and in *h5* I can receive *'ready to work'*. But after `subprocess.Popen()`, I can't receive *'sucess'* or *'failed'*, it seems stopped.

Any help ?

```
this is part of flask

@socketio.on('work')
def towork():
    t=threading.Thread(target=test)
    t.start()

def test():
    socketio.emit('listen',{'res':'ready to work'})
    cmd='dir'
    out=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    status=out.wait()
    if status==0:
        socketio.emit('listen',{'res':'sucess'})
    else:
        socketio.emit('listen',{'res':'failed'})

part of h5

socket.on("listen",function(msg){
    $('#show').append(`<p>{msg.res}</p>`);
});
```